# Возможно ли получить доступ к фалйу linux, если у тебя нет к нему доступа, и у тебя нет sudo?

Tags: linux

Хочу понять одну вещь:

Возможно ли штатными средствами Linux "грубо" скопировать файл к которому у тебя нет доступа вообще? Т.е перенести либо к себе на компьютер, открыв ее, либо просто открыть каким либо штатным средством?

Я стою под обычным пользователем, без каких либо прав (sudo,su).
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Если прав на чтение нет то никак.

Comment: Загрузитесь с CD или флэшки, примонтируйте HDD и копируйте на здоровье! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Ну, если бы такой способ был - то куда бы годилась вся эта хвалёная система разделения прав?

Хотя - случаи бывали, достаточно вспомнить [Heartbleed](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed) или более новые, но не так широко разрекламированные уязвимости.

Опять таки, при физическом доступе к компьютеру много чего можно сделать.

А так... Если будут идеи насчет того, как сделать это без уязвимости нулевого дня и без физического доступа к компу - я буду за вас только рад!

**Дополнение, дополненное 8 марта:**

Вам повезло! Есть уязвимость нулевого дня, пишет [арстехника](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2022/03/linux-has-been-bitten-by-its-most-high-severity-vulnerability-in-years/)

Правда, как я понял, речь идёт о том, чтобы *перезаписать* любой файл. Но всё равно - круто.

И цитирую из канала addmeto в телеграмме:

"В ядре Linux самая серьезная уязвимость за последние годы. За модным названием Dirty Pipe скрывается возможность от имени непривелегированного пользователя перезаписать содержимое любого файла. Совсем любого, в том числе и защищенного. Как следствие можно сделать с системой вообще всё, в том числе и получить рутовый доступ. Список ограничений и возможностей можете подглядеть в статье, самое важное для обычных пользователей - да, Андроид тоже уязвим, стоит быть аккуратнее"

Comment: Круто -- *`"allow anyone ... to add an SSH key to the root user's account"`*  / / Слишком сложной стала система, слишком много "разработчиков"... Наверное, пора откатываться поближе к истокам